# Data type to map defined/static properties to homogeneous data type

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want a data type where I can define a map from key->val where val is guaranteed to be the same type (e.x str). I would also like to be able to iterate the values.

https://github.com/irgeek/StrEnum comes really close, but, VSCode doesn't complain when put an int property in when I want it to.

TypeDict, Dataclass, NamedTuple all come close but do not force all the properties to be of the same type. Pydantic is also an option.

In a sense, what I want is `typing.dict[str, str]` where there are defined properties rather than dynamic keys.

Concretely, I originally was working with an enum, and then I wrote some code to iterate over the values, and then I ran into the problem that I didn't know for certain that each value was a string. I know as the developer that each value is a string, but I want VSCode to *know* this.

Maybe there is some fancy .pyi file I could write. I could of course write a custom class, or some custom generator that will filter non strings, but that's not the point.

Thanks!

p.s. technically I'm using 3.9.6 at the moment, so a solution for that is preferred but not necessarily.

edit: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1555 feels related

Comment: "I want VSCode to know this" ... are you talking about type hinting, or throwing an error when it's not the expected type?

Comment: Just regular `dict` with `dict[str, str]` would work. Also, all the other examples you gave would work, so it **really isn't clear what the precise problem is**. For example, `TypedDict` allows you to annoate all the values as a specific type, so does `NamedTuple`, and `dataclass` (note, dataclass isn't a *type* it is a code generator that generates a regular class, i.e. a regular type)

Comment: re 1: This is all about type hinting!

re 2: The problem with dict[str, str] is that the keys are not predefined. No auto completion on the keys, vulnerable to runtime errors. Dataclass/Namedtuple would allow me to define mixed type values which is not desired.

Comment: @sifh98h28fh29hews I don't understand. Why don't you just *define the types* in a regular class (i.e. a dataclass) or a `namedtuple`? So what if it *allows* you to defined mixed types, you can just use a single type

Comment: If it allows mixed types then I can't confidently iterate over the values without additional checking. (This is definitely a bit academic, just trying to achieve certainty with the type checker.)

Comment: @sifh98h28fh29hews yes, you *can* iterate over the values without additional checking, because **you told the type checker there are only strings there**. Just try it with, say, a `NamedTuple`

Comment: I think the issue is that I'm wanting to define the type of all the properties in one place, on the class, or on the datastructure, so that all the properties get the same type. Subclassing NamedTuple has you set the type for each property individually. Yes, I can define only strings on NamedTuple, but I want to be prevented from defining something else.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any of the approaches you already mentioned. So use a `NamedTuple` or a regularly defined class (e.g., using the `dataclasses.dataclass` decorator):

Just as one exampe, a `NamedTuple`:

```
(py310) jarrivillaga-mbp16-2019:~ jarrivillaga$ cat test.py
import typing

class Foo(typing.NamedTuple):
    bar: str
    baz: str

some_string:str = ""
for x in Foo('foo', 'bar'):
    some_string = some_string + x
    reveal_type(x)
```

First, with mypy:

```
(py310) jarrivillaga-mbp16-2019:~ jarrivillaga$ mypy test.py
test.py:10: note: Revealed type is "builtins.str"
```

Or pyright (which I'm pretty sure is what VS Code uses):

```
(py310) jarrivillaga-mbp16-2019:~ jarrivillaga$ pyright test.py
No configuration file found.
No pyproject.toml file found.
stubPath /Users/jarrivillaga/typings is not a valid directory.
Assuming Python platform Darwin
Searching for source files
Found 1 source file
/Users/jarrivillaga/test.py
  /Users/jarrivillaga/test.py:10:17 - info: Type of "x" is "str"
0 errors, 0 warnings, 1 info
Completed in 0.491sec
```

Versions:

```
(py310) jarrivillaga-mbp16-2019:~ jarrivillaga$ mypy --version
mypy 0.910
(py310) jarrivillaga-mbp16-2019:~ jarrivillaga$ pyright --version
pyright 1.1.193
```

Comment: is there a way to prevent someone adding `other: int` to `Foo`?